# How to make the left div has a small triangle protruding into the div on the right?

Tags: html, css

[image: Image for visualization]

Hi everyone. I am new to HTML and CSS and I want to create something like the figure in the picture. The two rectangles are divs and I want the left div has a little triangle protruding onto the div on the right.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

/**** Edit ****/
Seems like what I am looking for is pseudo-elements! I do not want the triangle to interfere with the content of the right div.

My English is limited so I did not know how to phrase what I want in a Google search.

Thanks a lot for everything!!

Comment: Define "protruding"?  Should it interfere with how content flows?  If not, you might look into z-order or background-image

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Try it yourself, come back when you're stuck and share what you've tried.

Comment: Hint: look into the `::after` CSS pseudoselector.

Comment: a pseudo-element with absolute position ... do a small google search, this is a common stuff

Comment: David Walsh wrote an article about CSS triangles that might be a [good starting place](https://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles).

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Now I can do some researches on Google. Pardon my English since I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element `:after` to add your triangle like this:

```css
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #888;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 left: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: "";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 border-left-color: #888;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

Comment: I did not know about pseudo-elements. I will learn more. Thank you for your suggestion. I am sorry I cannot upvote because I dont have enough reputation. :( – user2731449 40 secs ago   edit